# 3G USB modem not responding to AT commands

Tags: android, 3g, modem

I have a 3G modem (ZTE MF-210) plugged as a mini-pci daugther board into my tablet.

I'm trying to integrate that as part of my Open Source Android JB porting project:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/renesas-emev-osp

So, I have modified my kernel in order to include USB-serial GSM modem support, by adding these config options:

```
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_WWAN=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_OPTION=y
```

I have included the code to enable power up of the 3G module (controlled by SoC GPIO pins). 
This part looks like working, as far as I can understand at least. When the modem gets powered up, I get these logs in dmesg:

```
6>usb 1-1.1: new high speed USB device using emxx-ehci-driver and address 9
<6>option 1-1.1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_startup
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_setup_urbs
<6>usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
<6>option 1-1.1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_startup
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_setup_urbs
<6>usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
<6>option 1-1.1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_startup
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_setup_urbs
<6>usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
<6>option 1-1.1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_startup
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_setup_urbs
<6>usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_open
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_dtr_rts
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_set_termios
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write_room: 16384
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: write (8 chars)
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: endpoint 2 buf 0
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: wrote (did 8)
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write_room: 12288
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: write (1 chars)
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: endpoint 2 buf 1
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_outdat_callback
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: wrote (did 1)
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_outdat_callback
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_indat_callback: c78f9640
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_indat_callback: c78f9140
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_indat_callback: c78f90c0
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write_room: 16384
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: write (8 chars)
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: endpoint 2 buf 0
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: wrote (did 8)
...
```

Note as I have enabled debugging in usb_wwan.c

I get the following on file system:

```
# ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*                                          
crw-rw---- radio    radio    188,   0 2013-05-22 15:50 ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- radio    radio    188,   1 2013-05-22 15:51 ttyUSB1
crw-rw---- radio    radio    188,   2 2013-05-22 15:50 ttyUSB2
crw------- root     root     188,   3 2013-05-22 15:50 ttyUSB3

# cat /proc/tty/driver/usbserial                                
usbserinfo:1.0 driver:2.0
0: name:"GSM modem (1-port)" vendor:19d2 product:2003 num_ports:1 port:1 path:usb-emxx_ehci-1.1
1: name:"GSM modem (1-port)" vendor:19d2 product:2003 num_ports:1 port:1 path:usb-emxx_ehci-1.1
2: name:"GSM modem (1-port)" vendor:19d2 product:2003 num_ports:1 port:1 path:usb-emxx_ehci-1.1
3: name:"GSM modem (1-port)" vendor:19d2 product:2003 num_ports:1 port:1 path:usb-emxx_ehci-1.1
```

Standing to some info I found on the net (e.g. http://blog.csdn.net/vishtvro/article/details/7505915; I'm not sure how to verify that directly, as I don't have 'lsusb -v' on Android OS and busybox doesn't help), the four ports correspond to:

```
ttyUSB3: Modem
ttyUSB1: AT
ttyUSB0: Debug
ttyUSB2: VoUSB
```

Issue is that I'm not able to communicate with those ports, using 'picocom' or 'busybox microcom'. I can connects to it, but can't send or receive commands:

```
# picocom /dev/ttyUSB1 -b 115200
picocom v1.6

port is        : /dev/ttyUSB1
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115200
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,

Terminal ready
<blinking cursor here>
```

Typing a character is reported in usb_wwan.c debug logs e.g.

```
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_chars_in_buffer: 0
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write_room: 16384
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_chars_in_buffer: 0
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write_room: 16384
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: write (1 chars)
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: endpoint 1 buf 0
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write: wrote (did 1)
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_chars_in_buffer: 1
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_write_room: 12288
<7>drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c: usb_wwan_outdat_callback
```

but it's not echoed on console, nor I get any result back if I type any AT command. 'AT' should return with 'OK' - that's the basic expectation to me, but I see nothing.

I've searched long on the net and here on stackexchange, but couldn't find any useful hint, until now.

Any suggestion about how to debug this problem?

NOTE - on a stock GB Android firmware the modem works as expected - unfortunately I don't have that GB code...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One more point... I'm missing `usb/` under both `/proc/bus` and `/sys/kernel/debug`. On the other hand, in spite I get four `/dev/ttyUSB*` devices, I only get first one under `/dev/usb/*`. I.e.: 

`root@android:/ # ls -l /dev/usb                                                
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-05-27 09:48 tty1-1.1 -> /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: I made some **partial** progress, using picocom "-i" option (no port init), but this is what I get if I simply type A + T + Z + <enter> afters starting picocom: `Terminal ready
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATATATATATATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZATZ
ERROR
ATZ
OK`. Single characters, as well as the entire command are repeated several times. But, at least I get the 'OK' back, sometimes.
What could be happening here? Any idea?

Comment: Same modem, used withing the AT command interface of the (AOSP) RIL framework works perfectly, answering to AT commands as expected.